# How can i set multidimensional foreach loop in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have two foreach loop and its working fine. But I need data in different format. Please view below code.

Code

```
$data['categories'] = array();
foreach ($allCategories as $result) {
        $data['categories'][] = array(
                'name' => $result['name'],
                'Cat_id' => $result['category_id']
        );
        $productData= $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($productID);
        foreach ($productData as $singleProduct) {


            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'product_id'  => $singleProduct['product_id'],
                'thumb'       => $image,
                'name'        => $singleProduct['name'],
                'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($singleProduct['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
                'price'       => $price,
                'special'     => $special,
                'tax'         => $tax,
                'minimum'     => $singleProduct['minimum'] > 0 ? $singleProduct['minimum'] : 1,
                'rating'      => $rating,
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $singleProduct['product_id'])
            );

         }

    }
```

### Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => sweflora special
            [Cat_id] => 59
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 52
            [thumb] => http://localhost/swefloraProject/upload/image/cache/catalog/birthday/home-product-01-80x80.png
            [name] => gift flowers
            [description] => when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has ..
            [price] => $0.00
            [special] => 
            [tax] => $0.00
            [minimum] => 1
            [rating] => 0
            [href] => http://localhost/swefloraProject/upload/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=52
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => birthday
            [Cat_id] => 61
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 53
            [thumb] => http://localhost/swefloraProject/upload/image/cache/catalog/birthday/flower2-80x80.jpg
            [name] => test flower
            [description] => ..
            [price] => $86.00
            [special] => 
            [tax] => $86.00
            [minimum] => 1
            [rating] => 0
            [href] => http://localhost/swefloraProject/upload/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=53
        )
  )
```

I want to change the array format. Currently it is directly showing categories and products. But I need an array like this format.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => sweflora special
            [Cat_id] => 59

           [Products] =>  Array
            (
                [product_id] => 52
                [thumb] => http://localhost/Project/upload/image/cache/catalog/birthday/home-product-01-80x80.png
                [name] => gift flowers
                [description] => when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has ..
                [price] => $0.00
                [special] => 
                [tax] => $0.00
                [minimum] => 1
                [rating] => 0
                [href] => http://localhost/Project/upload/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=52
            )
            [Products] =>  Array
            (
                [product_id] => 52
                [thumb] => http://localhost/swefloraProject/upload/image/cache/catalog/birthday/home-product-01-80x80.png
                [name] => gift flowers
                [description] => when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has ..
                [price] => $0.00
                [special] => 
                [tax] => $0.00
                [minimum] => 1
                [rating] => 0
                [href] => http://localhost/Project/upload/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=52
            )
        )

      [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => sweflora special
            [Cat_id] => 60

           [Products] =>  Array
            (
                [product_id] => 52
                [thumb] => http://localhost/Project/upload/image/cache/catalog/birthday/home-product-01-80x80.png
                [name] => gift flowers
                [description] => when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has ..
                [price] => $0.00
                [special] => 
                [tax] => $0.00
                [minimum] => 1
                [rating] => 0
                [href] => http://localhost/Project/upload/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=52
            )
            [Products] =>  Array
            (
                [product_id] => 52
                [thumb] => http://localhost/Project/upload/image/cache/catalog/birthday/home-product-01-80x80.png
                [name] => gift flowers
                [description] => when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has ..
                [price] => $0.00
                [special] => 
                [tax] => $0.00
                [minimum] => 1
                [rating] => 0
                [href] => http://localhost/Project/upload/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=52
            )
        )


  )
```

I have used `array_push` and `array_combine` but did solve this issue. Can any one please guide me how can i convert to this format. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the nested `foreach` should add elements to a new internal array for each category, I think. You can't get *exactly* the structure you posted, in which you associate the key 'Products' to multiple objects, but you can build a nested array of products instead. So I would try this:

```
    foreach ($productData as $singleProduct) {
        $data['categories']['Products'][] = array(/* Your element */);
```

Edit: we need to keep the bound with category, so I would do:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($allCategories as $result) {
    $data['categories'][$i] = array(
            'name' => "N",
            'Cat_id' => "C",
            'Products' => array()
    );
    $productData= $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($productID);
    foreach ($productData as $singleProduct){
        $data['categories'][$i]['Products'][] = array(
            /* Your product */);

     }
$i++;
}
```

Comment: thanks but array format still is not correct. Because all the products are showing in first category.

Comment: I edit the answer: basically in my previous solution there were no bound between category and products... with an index we add the product in the proper category (without changing too much your code). It should work even without pre-declaring the field 'Products' as an array